# How to measure the degree of concentration for a matrix

Tags: matrix

A *normal* image(from nature) have a smooth transition.Then we can use `ImageCooccurrence` to get a matrix(*whose sum of all the elements is 1*) like

```
img = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}];
MatrixPlot[mat=ImageCooccurrence[img, 100]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

As we see,the `mat` have a good degree of concentration **on the diagonal**.But if you just use `img = RandomImage[]` to get a random image.you cannot get such result.It will be

[image: Mathematica graphics]

My question is how to measure the degree of concentration of a matrix?

For example,this matrix:
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0.5 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0.2 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0.3 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
I think its have a degree of concentration is 1.And this matrix:
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
I think its have a degree of concentration **on the diagonal** is 0. Is a good solution can do this?

Comment: …I think this isn't a _Mathematica_ problem? You're looking for a criterion judging the degree of concentration, I think you should ask this in https://math.stackexchange.com/ or https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: @xzczd Wow,indeed,but it is produce in *MMA*.if other think as you think I will transform it to that site.Thanks. :)

Comment: As @xzczd says, this isn't a *Mathematica* problem... yet. Why not research and look at papers for an algorithm, and then come back to ask how that algorithm can be implemented?

Comment: @J.M. I post my implement in following just.You are a math Big God in mind.Could you give some advice for me?

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1392491/measure-of-how-much-diagonal-a-matrix-is) seems very much like the question you're having.

Comment: @ThiesHeidecke Thanks, that's very very useful link. :)

Answer (score 3):

One possibility is to sum all the elements and compare this to the sum of the diagonal elements.

```
Tr[Abs[mat]]/Total[Abs[mat], 2]
```

So for a random matrix

```
mat1 = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {10, 10}];
Tr[Abs[mat1]]/Total[Abs[mat1], 2]
0.0905167
```

while for a mostly diagonal matrix:

```
mat2 = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {10, 10}] + DiagonalMatrix[RandomReal[{-100, 100}, 10]];
Tr[Abs[mat2]]/Total[Abs[mat2], 2]
0.922929
```

At least it will always be between zero and one. A problem with the above answer is that it weights all off-diagonal elements the same. The spirit of the OPs request is that elements far from the diagonal should carry more weight. We can implement this via a weight matrix:

```
par=1.2;
weights = Table[par^Abs[i - j], {i, Length[mat1]}, {j, Length[mat1]}];

Tr[Abs[weights mat1]]/Total[Abs[weights mat1], 2]
0.0497874

Tr[Abs[weights mat2]]/Total[Abs[weights mat2], 2]
0.83005
```

You can play with the parameter par to choose how much weight should be given to the distant diagonal terms terms.

Answer (score 1):

For a matrix whose elements sum to one, `Tr` would seem to do what you want.

Comment: That's a good start,but sometimes,the elements is not concentre in the diagonal precisely,but in the near post.such as [this matrix](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Bka9q.png),I think it have a good degree of concentration still.

Answer (score 1):

This is current method,suppose the `mat` is

```
mat = {{0, .2, 0, 0},
   {0, .1, .2, 0},
   {0, .2, 0, 0},
   {0, .2, .1, 0}};
```

I will built a `const`,which contain all distance form the position of the element to the diagonal.

```
const = Dispatch[
   Thread[Rule[#, 
       Normalize[Abs[Subtract @@ #]/Sqrt[2] & /@ #, Total]]] &[
    Tuples[Range[Length[mat]], 2]]];
```

Then I get a rule about the element and its postion

```
rule = Most[ArrayRules[mat]]
```

> `{{1, 2} -> 0.2, {2, 2} -> 0.1, {2, 3} -> 0.2, {3, 2} -> 0.2, {4, 2} ->0.2, {4, 3} -> 0.1}`

Measure the degree of concentration

```
1 - Mean[WeightedData[Values[rule], Keys[rule] /. const]]
```

> `0.816667`

But I don't sure how to ensure the result always between 0 to 1.A better solution is expected still.

---

Packed it into a function for using

```
Concentration[mat_] := 
 Module[{const, rule = Most[ArrayRules[mat]]}, 
  const = Dispatch[
    Thread[Rule[#, 
        Normalize[Abs[Subtract @@ #]/Sqrt[2] & /@ #, Total]]] &[
     Tuples[Range[Length[mat]], 2]]]; 
  1 - Mean[WeightedData[Values[rule], Keys[rule] /. const]]]
```

Comment: Did you come up with this yourself, or did you get this from some reference?

Comment: @J.M. Actually from my mind..If I have referenced,I will add that link always.